# UIActivityViewController Messenger not working on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm getting the following result when I try to initialize the `Messenger` component of `UIActivityViewController`:

[image]

I'm using this code to instantiate my `UIActivityViewController`:

```
 NSString *textToShare = @"Text that will be shared";
        NSArray *itemsToShare = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:textToShare, nil];
        UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, nil];
        [activityVC setValue:@"My Subject Text" forKey:@"subject"];
        [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I then get the following error in my logs when I attempt to send with `Message`

```
Launch Services: Unable to find app identifier com.apple.MobileSMS
2013-07-31 01:27:15.180 Coolist[54111:c07] Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <MFMessageComposeViewController: 0xa38db30>.
```

**Is this just a simulator problem?**

Comment: check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910366/what-is-the-bundle-identifier-of-apples-default-applications-in-ios test app in device not simulator.

Comment: iMessage don't work on simulator. Test yourself

Comment: The iOS simulator does not have a Messages app, and can't simulate message sending (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012393/testing-sms-in-the-ios-simulator)).

Comment: @iT if you notice, though, the simulator doesn't have the Mail app either, but it simulates mail creation just fine. I find this odd. But yea, thanks for the advice guys.