# Xcode "Device Locked" When iPhone is unlocked

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When I tried to build and run, Xcode said my device was locked. I looked at my iPhone, and it's not locked at all. How do I fix this?

Comment: lock it and unlock it again

Comment: tried it, still no luck

Comment: For me, unplugging and re-plugging did the trick. No need to Clean Build Folder, restart Mac with Command+Option+P+R, leave the house and come back again, burn a Voodoo doll of Steve Jobs, etc.

Comment: I solved this issue with disabling hotspot

Comment: @NicolasMiari For me it has not worked and I am looking for the Voodoo doll

Comment: Continuous issue. disconnect+connect sometimes solve it.

Comment: Four years later, I'm using Xcode 9.2 and iOS 11.2, and this issue is still live and kicking.  This cr*p just doesn't get any better, does it...?

Comment: In my case (I use wireless debugging) simply opening Window > Devices & Simulators caused Xcode to automatically detect my device, fixing the issue. Note: I had already "trusted" my device and used it previously.

Comment: First unlock your device, then plug in the cable

Comment: Quit Xcode and reopen project.

Comment: worked for me in Xcode 10:
step 1 : Unplug and re-plug device 
step 2: Go to menu > Devices and simulator > un check Connect via network: Done

Comment: If you have already trusted your device, make sure your iPhone is unlocked when you connect or plug in. This works for me!!

Comment: for me, re-plugging is worked

Comment: it's 2021 and Xcode13 still does this weird behaviour. unplug, restart iPhone and Xcode, wait a good 10 secs or so after both rebooted, then reconnect and wait a few minutes, or just build the project on Xcode.

Comment: I tried almost all the suggestions from all the answers, except the Voodoo doll though, and the problem turned out to be a pending update of my iPhone. always keep your software updated when developing in Apple environment (on MAC and iPhone) or you are going to face bizarre issues. It's 2022 now.

Comment: restart xcode worked

Comment: It's 2023 and Xcode 14.2 still has this issue. Restarting iPhone and/or Xcode may work but it's just unacceptable after so long!

Comment: happens mostly if your device is paired by internet, and you plug it. Before plugging, switch to the "Any iOS device".

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Did you by chance not "trust" the device? This will prevent it from communicating with xcode even if the device is unlocked.

Update here's a support doc from Apple: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5868

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "trust"...how do i enable that?

Comment: Unplug the device, close xcode, and then open xcode and plugin the device. When you plug it in (after unlocking it) it you should be prompted to "trust" the computer (in the iOS device). My guess is you may have accidentally tapped "do not trust" and so the device will refuse to connect to the computer.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to apple support page regarding the issue.

Comment: This is really weird because in my case, I was never prompted to trust in the first place...

Comment: @NicolasMiari I've had other notifications show up at the same time I plug in my phone causing it disappear, or accidentally dismissing the prompt on my Mac... as well, if you've used mobile configurator there is a chance it's causing some weird issues as the device could be configured to only respond to one machine. Perhaps that handshake got messed up the first time you plugged it in?

Comment: There is also an additional step to run the app on phone , you have to trust the developer profile inside your iPhone settings .

Comment: Ah ... another one of those "jiggle the switch" solutions.

Comment: @tehprofessor I didn't need to tap Trust again since the computer was already trusted, but your advice to "Unplug the device, close xcode, and then open xcode and plugin the device" worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Adding for this solution:   If the "Trust" popup doesn't appear, in Xcode go to "Devices & Simulator" -> Unpair your device, and then unplug and plug, the "Trust" popup should appear.

Answer (score 562):

My phone was set to "trust" the Mac, and I still ran into this error with Xcode 6.1.1.

This worked for me:

- unplug device
- quit xcode
- open xcode
- plug in device
- build/run

Comment: Unfortunately this is too often the solution for many of your weird Xcode woes.

Comment: "did you try turning it off and on again?!" - works every time!

Comment: November 2019 and Xcode still has this problem! It hit me this morning. unplug device, quit Xcode, (go get more coffee), open Xcode, plug in, big time sink but seems to work. My other "favorite" is Xcode sees the device then doesn't see the device.

Comment: XCode 10.1 and still had to do this to get it to deploy to device.  Some things never change.

Comment: as of the latest Xcode 11.4.1... this is till the answer

Comment: If this does not work, just turn off and turn on the device again. It worked for me in Xcode 12 and Ipad with Ios 14

Comment: April 2022 still a working solution.

Comment: 8+ years after this solution was posted, it's still needed -- need to restart XCode

Answer (score 122):

I recently ran into this issue with XCode 8 just after updating my device from iOS 9 to 10. The exact error I received was:`Development cannot be enabled while your device is locked. Please unlock your device and reattach.` I received this error even when my phone was unlocked, and after unplugging and re-plugging in the device.

As is mentioned in several answers, the `device is locked` message is actually referring to the device not trusting the MacBook. In my case, I think my phone defaulted to not trusting my computer after updating to iOS 10. Here are the steps that worked for me to reset the settings (this is the same process that is mentioned in the Apple support page in tehprofessors' answer):

1. Disconnect your device from your MacBook and close Xcode.
2. On your device go to `Settings > General > Reset`, then tap `Reset Location & Privacy`
3. Plug your device back into your computer, and on the device you will be prompted to trust the computer. Tap trust.
4. Now reopen Xcode and rebuild the project.
5. The `device locked` error should disappear.

Comment: yep unfortunately only this worked for me on from Xcode 8 on iOS 10 :(

Comment: @BishalGhimire Yeah, it's definitely not ideal. I actually just had to do this reset again as XCode started giving me the `device is locked` message again without any noticeable changes to any of my iPhone's settings or XCode's settings. Somewhere along the way my trust settings for my computer are being reset, but I'm not sure when and where.

Comment: you should wait for a while to processing symbol files

Comment: Hmm... this fixed the "Device Locked" error ... but has replaced it with a "Could not save the pairing record." error ...

Comment: this worked for me after iOS 11 software update on device / Xcode 9

Comment: This appeared to work for me at first as it did prompt me to trust my computer again, I had to enter my password, it paired, but now it says that my device has denied the request. It's interesting to note as well that despite it not launching a debug session it would install and launch the app from Xcode as if the device was already trusted. I really don't know what to do at this point other than try a factory reset.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! In Russian, it was "geolocation" menu item. Worked for me.

Comment: There's no need to reset the location and privacy setting, which affect the whole iPhone. This answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/48799977/2686243

Answer (score 88):

From the Window Menu in top bar of Xcode, select Devices and Simulators.

> (or Press SHIFT + COMMAND + 2)

Then select your device, right click and select Unpair. 
Once you do this Trust or Don't trust will appear on your device. 
Trust the device again and it will begin preparing it for Development. 
Wait for Xcode to pair device for development and then you are good to go!

Comment: The problem usually is not waiting for xcode to prepare iPhone to debug :) this worked

Comment: detailed instructions for unpair can be found in https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52048

Comment: I'm having this problem in Xcode 11 beta and iOS 13 beta, and this worked to solve the issue of "Passcode Required" Xcode prompt when enabling wireless debugging. Thank you! :)

Comment: This solution worked for me after I have tried to enable wireless.
The rest of the answers did not help.

Answer (score 47):

I ran in to the same issue even though i selected "Trust this computer" option first time.

This worked for me

1. Lock the device
2. Remove cable from device.
3. Unlock the device
4. Connect again to Mac

Comment: Abhi Beckert's answer above worked for me before, this worked for me now. I spend a ridiculously large amount of my time tap-dancing around Apple's inept developers.

Comment: thats aApple for you! changing some value in IB's attribute inspector will make your xcode faster. lol.

Answer (score 43):

#### 2018

The fastest way for now i found is:

1) Go to **Window -> devices** (changed the hotkey in xcode to CMD+P for me)
2) Press **unpair** on the device. [image]
3) Press **trust** in iPhone.
4) Build again or Run without building (Ctrl+CMD+R)

Comment: It works. And now I know Cmd + Ctrl + R to run without build

Answer (score 25):

I have a very simple solution which worked for me instantly. Takes some 10 sec to do:

1) Go to **`Window -> Devices & Simulators`** and untick `Show as run destination`

[image]

2) Unplug the cable and plug it back in.

3) Run the project.

This should be solving your problem!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me with XCode 10.2 when the other advice didn't. May be related to having previously ticked to be available over network then being on a rather slow wifi.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Xcode 11.3. Funny because unplugging the cable and plugging it back in didn't work, when I didnt open Devices & Simulators window.

Comment: Um, that seems to just make it not be available to select as the destination. What am I missing?

Comment: Most probably you forgot to follow the 2nd step: ```2) Unplug the cable and plug it back in. Run the project.```

Comment: Not working for Xcode 13.4.1 on MacBook Monterey

Answer (score 24):

## Rebooted my iPhone, and that fixed it for me.

I tried every answer on this page (7 at the time, though 2 are duplicates) and they were all unsuccessful for getting rid of this Xcode error for me.

Comment: This saved my day! Thank you!

Comment: This is the best answer which save my lot of time. Thanks

Comment: Didn't helped for me. Only setting untrusted and trust again helped.

Comment: You don't need to reboot or restart every time..check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50023756/9623144

Comment: It's a waste of time to reboot the phone every time.

Comment: Agreed. If it is happening regularly you need a better solution. It only happened to me once and I tried a dozen other solutions before rebooting. It hasn't happened to be again.

Answer (score 21):

For anyone who need a logical answer..

1. Go to Window -> Devices & Simulators. Right click on your device & unpair it.
2. Disconnect from cable & reconnect.
3. Wait for it & let Xcode detect you device.
4. Run the project.
5. Make sure you **TRUST** on your iOS device and enter any passcode.

Comment: This worked. Make sure your device is UNLOCKED when you initially pair it. If not then follow these instructions to repair.

Answer (score 12):

For those who has this issue in Xcode 9:
Simply restarting Xcode should solve the problem.

Comment: This is correct and especially true in the case of wifi debugging in Xcode 9.

Answer (score 12):

This happens at times while using Xcode 9.

[image: Screenshot]

There are multiple solution to this as mentioned below :

***Note :*** Make sure that your device is not locked when Xcode is trying to install app.

**Solution 1 :**

i. `Disconnect device` and `connect again`

**Solution 2 :**

i. `Restart you device`

**Solution 3 :**

i. `Disconnect device`

ii. `Quit Xcode` (Shortcut key : `cmd + Q)`

iii. `Open your project`

iv. `Clean project` (Shortcut key : `cmd + shift + K`)

v. Now `connect device`

vi. `Run` your project

*For me Solution 3 worked perfectly*

Comment: Tried just about everything in the book. Restarting my phone was the only thing that worked in the end. Thanks for posting that idea here!

Answer (score 11):

There is a simple way to resolve that. At least it works for me.
In your iPhone Device
Go to Setting > Developer > click in “Clear Trusted Computer”
Type the passcode required
And done!!!

The simplest way that I found.

Comment: What if there is no Settings > Developer visible?

Comment: @Dronz This is usually only visible when you had the device at least once connected.

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me. Xcode 13.3.x here.

Comment: This is the way! It should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 10):

A simple solution:

1. First, unplug your device.
2. Now, unlock your device and plug it in again. Be sure that the device is unlocked.
3. Now run the Xcode project by selecting the device as target.

Comment: The same for me. With addition that I was able to debug wireless.

Comment: @MykhailoLysenko Oh, It means you have to shutdown your iPhone's network for a moment thanks for Steven Jobs. : )

Answer (score 8):

When you plug in your iPhone, it will ask you to trust the computer.
If you already trust and unlocked but still said your device was locked (bug). Just unplug and plug again then it will work

Answer (score 8):

These steps worked for me in iOS 10.

1. Remove the cable from device.
2. Plug in the device.
3. Clean and build the Xcode project.

Answer (score 8):

I run into this problem quite often (at least like 5 times a week). Almost every time this happens, a Xcode restart fixes it. But this time nothing seemed to work including:

- Restarting Xcode;
- Unplugging and re-plugging the iPhone;
- Cleaning the project (cmd+shift+k);
- Cleaning derived data (cmd+option+shift+k)

Done dozens of times in all sorts of different orders.

What fixed the issue for me this time was simply:

✅ Rebooting the Mac.

Comment: This one worked for me, Though, I killed the Xcode too.

Answer (score 7):

Recently I have met the Xcode shows "development cannot be enabled while your device is locked, Please unlock your device and reattach. (0xE80000E2).

If your iOS device is already unlocked and connected to mac and still get the error from Xcode 8.1 after upgrading to iOS 10.1.1, then the mac is not trusted by the device.

To fix it, first disconnect device to mac and then go to iOS settings app, and open general->reset->Reset Location & Privacy.

Then connect device to mac and when prompted, set select trust the mac.

Then wait the processing symbol files within your device and mac. After it finished, you can run the project to your device. It will be working.

Answer (score 7):

I spent hours trying to fix this issue with no luck.

BE SURE TO DISABLE ANY VPN SERVICES FROM YOUR IPHONE.  Just like magic, it started working properly.

Comment: that's F ed up
a hole week and I didn't try that, its working now after I disabled VPN

Answer (score 6):

This issue is not about "Trust" or not. It's a bug in Xcode.

Just follow these steps.

When Xcode is running and your device is connected:

1. Lock your device.
2. Unplug your device from Mac.
3. Unlock your device.
4. Plug your device back to Mac.

Answer (score 4):

*Solution*: Switch target device to some other (e.g. Generic iOS Device),

[image]

then unlock you physical device and switch back to it again.

Answer (score 4):

there are two solution worked for me.
1) disconnect your device from the mac and reattach it.
2) disconnect your device from the mac and restart it and then connect it with mac it'll work

Answer (score 4):

What solved the issue for me was unplugging the phone, then going to Devices and Simulators:

[image]

Then right click on the device and select Unpair.
[image]

Then plug your phone back in, Select "Trust this computer" and you should be golden.

Answer (score 3):

Generally just unplugging/replugging seems to work for me. But today it didn't and something else seems to have worked: I have enabled *network debugging* on the device in question and it almost looked like it remembered an old network "lock" setting, while not seeing that the device was actually connected via USB. After (temporarily) de-selecting "*Connect via Network*" and replugging, it got things working again.

Comment: Yeah- disabling and re-enabling network debugging often fixes it for me, when even restarts failed.

Comment: So wifi debugging is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes your device stops trusting your PC for no reseaon. go to your settings then general > reset > reset location and privacy. and replug your device to your PC again and press "trust this device" prompt that shows up in your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of answers, but the one that worked for me (El Capitan, Xcode 8.2) was to close iTunes.  If that has a connection to the IOS device then although Xcode can load the app components it will still fail to run it.

Answer (score 1):

On your device (iPhone/iPad) goto: **Settings** -> **Developer** -> **Clear Trusted Computers** worked for me.

Comment: this is what I had to do as well to get the 'trust this computer?'  prompt to appear when I connected to my computer

Answer (score 1):

I found that by shutting down a Console and a running Simulator allowed XCode to see my iPhone again. I'd make sure other related programs aren't running if you don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen due to pending update on your device. This also means you need to update your phone, connect to the MacBook (trust it if needed). This how I found my problem and solution.

Comment: I had the same problem (update was waiting on device) but I didn't have time to update it. Asfand Shabbir's answer worked. (in case readers don't have time to update)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility worth checking, if none of these other solutions work, is that there is no space left on the device.  Xcode will not give you a helpful "device full" error to tell you that your device has no storage space left, but it will also not be able to deploy an app build to a device whose storage is full.  The only solution in that situation is to delete media or other apps/data to free up enough space.

Answer (score 1):

Bizare, but I hope it helps someone. 
I was connected to a VPN (Pro XPN) and that was causing the issue! Disconnected and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

What fixed the issue for me:
the USB<->lightning cable had to be connected directly through the mac, not through my LG 5k display (which is also a USB hub).

Answer (score 0):

Another fix to this problem is to connect your iPhone with your Xcode open while your iPhone is in the homescreen, not in lockscreen or with an app opened.

Answer (score 0):

All the previous solutions didn't work.

Finlay, changing the iPhone's cable solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-add device to xcode.

In XCode open Devices and Simulators (CMD+Shift+2), in left list press + button and re-add the same device.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Low Power Mode" in disabled. In my case I just disable this check and the deploy works immediately,

Answer (score 0):

For me, when I was about to unpair my device from xcode, I noticed it was just  Preparing debugger support for my iPhone and it told me that "Xcode will continue when iPhone is finished."
Similar to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316373/xcode-9-iphone-is-busy-preparing-debugger-support-for-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I was trying to install on an unsupported (new) iOS version which produced the same errors.
Specifically Xcode 11.7 to iOS 14

Answer (score 0):

For me my iPhone 12 has a connected Apple Watch, I had to trust my computer on my Apple Watch as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple solution. The only real solution is to reboot the Mac, restart XCode and the iPhone. This is a shame, because it can happen at any time even in the middle of a session where everything was perfectly working, device paired and unlocked as needed.
All other solutions given here or elsewhere can work here and now but fail tomorrow morning.

Comment: Thank you - I had a different DNS that blocks ads. This fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

This was happening on the Ventura (OSX 13.6) with Xcode 15.2

---

1. Go to `Window -> Devices & Simulators` on your Xcode: For some the iPhone was under both the connected and disconnected devices list at the same time.
2. Remove (unpair) iPhone: I removed iPhone from the connected and disconnected devices.
3. Disconnect from the Cable
4. On iPhone Go to `Settings -> Developer -> Clear Trusted Computers`
5. Connect with the Cable
6. Press "Trust" on alert
7. Select `iPhone` as a target to build and run the app

Answer (score -1):

I haven't seen this in any of the answers here, but the only thing that worked for me is an option on the device itself called Enable UI Automation. Supposedly it will turn itself off after an update. Go to Settings, Developer, then find Enable UI Automation.

This worked on my iPad 6th generation.

Answer (score -1):

Check that on the "Runner" option is selected the correct device. Although you have one device physically plugged in with a cable, Xcode could have connected via WiFi to any other device that has the "Connect via network" option enabled.

[image: Check the "Runner" device (3rd Top Left button after the "build & run", and the "stop" buttons)]

Comment: Issue clearly says "Xcode "Device Locked" When iPhone is unlocked", so device will be connected in that case.